# lein run migration doesn't create a database

Tags: sqlite, clojure, leiningen, luminus

when trying to migrate the following files,

```
drop table test2;
```

```
CREATE TABLE test2
(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
name VARCHAR(30),
message VARCHAR(200),
timestamp TIMESTAMP(7));
```

I got the following result:

```
2019-12-07 10:54:33,129 [main] INFO  migratus.core - Starting migrations 
2019-12-07 10:54:33,253 [main] DEBUG migratus.migrations - Looking for migrations in #object[java.io.File 0x4f880f4a /home/jonas/Dropbox/prog/web/clojure/test2/resources/migrations] 
2019-12-07 10:54:33,258 [main] INFO  migratus.core - Ending migrations
```

It seems that it doesn't find the connection and therefore no database is created. Could that be the case?

Comment: For future reference; it's best adviced to use the latest version of migratus since older ones don't run the migrations but also don't show any output on what could be wrong or missing. Had this same problem while reading Web Development with Clojure 2nd, which uses migratus "0.8.9", updated to "1.2.8" and everything works well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

found the solution, set the DATABASE_URL to the corresponding database:

```
export DATABASE_URL="jdbc:sqlite:./test2.db"
```

where test2 is the name of the app and sqlite is the name of the database